# Show convergence of the following series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I honestly am not sure how to start. I think we will use convergence of geometric series. This section has to do with rearrangement of series.

Prove that if $$0 \leq x \lt 1$$ then $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)x^n= (\frac{1}{1-x})^2$$

Comment: Hint: power rule.

Comment: Are you allowed to use termwise differentiation? If yes, just differentiate both sides of $\sum\limits_{n\geq 0}x^n=\dfrac 1{1-x}$ wrt $x$ and shift index because the derivative of the first term vanishes.

Comment: No, I think we can only use absolute convergence and rearrangement for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Integrate the general term of the series
$$\int (n+1) x^n \, dx=x^{n+1}+C$$
We know that
$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } x^{n+1}=\frac{1}{1-x}-1;\;|x|<1$$
Now differentiate and get the result
$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }(n+1)x^n=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2};\;|x|<1$$

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in my comment, the result follows immediately by termwise differentiation of the identity $\sum\limits_{n\geq 0}x^n=\dfrac 1{1-x}$ for $|x|\lt 1$

If you have to do it algebraically, note that,

$$\left(1+x+x^2+\ldots\right)\left(1+x+x^2+\ldots\right)=1+2x+3x^2+\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**-We have:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$$

and the convergence is absolute. Hence

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{d}{dx}x^n=\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{1-x}=\frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)^2}.$$

**Added**: $$F(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)x^n = 1+x + 2x^2 + 3x^3 + ...$$

$$xF(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1) x^{n+1} = x+ x^2 +2x^3  + ...$$

$$F(x) - xF(x) =1+ x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4... = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \dfrac{1}{1 - x}.$$
$$F(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1) x^n=\dfrac{1}{(1 - x)^2}.$$

Comment: Thank you. But we have not covered differentiation yet. I think we can only use absolute convergent and rearrangement of series theorems.

Comment: @AmyTheeNelson Yes , you can do by just manipulating the series.

Comment: Okay I see that now. Thanks!